# Как не дожидаться выполнение метода python

Tags: python, asyncio, task

как в пайтоне можно поставить метод на выполнение и не ждать пока он завершится, а идти дальше по коду, при этом не создавать новых потоков. У меня вот есть задача, но программа ждёт её выполнения

```
async def main():
for event in longpoll.listen():
       task = asyncio.create_task(newMessage(event))
       await task
```

и сам метод, который должен выполняться асинхронно

```
async def newMessage(event):
#some logic
```

Comment: `await task` уберите, очевидно?

Answer (score 0):

Убрать `await task` - таск уже запланирован через create_task - значит выполнится во время ожидания другой асинхронной функции.

`for event in longpoll.listen` блокирующий похоже, даже если убрать `await` - таск не выполнится потому как тред заблокирован.

async def main() - не делает код асинхронным. Нужно поменять библиотеку чтоб работать асинхронно. С этой библиотекой используйте треды:

```
def main():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
       task = threading.Thread(target=newMessage, args=(event,)).start()
```

А вот например асинхронная библиотека с асинхронным for: https://github.com/Fahreeve/aiovk#user-long-poll